# How to stop resharper solution wide analysis?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I clicked the resharper circle on the bottom right of my visual studio and selected the solution wide code analysis. 
The problem is, it got stuck at "4246 errors in 216 files". Now whenever I open up any visual studio with this project, visual studio completely freezes and I can't do anything in it.
I uninstalled resharper for one of the visual studios, which solves the freezing problem for that visual studio. But obviously, that means not having resharper.

Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 2):

I poked around on my projects and found that the setting seems to be saved in the `<yourProjectName>.csproj.DotSettings` which is in the same folder as the *.csproj file.

Upon turning the settings off for a project, the following gets added to that file:

```
<s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeInspection/Highlighting/UsageCheckingInspectionLevel/@EntryValue">Off</s:String>
```

You could try to create/add the file to your project and check if it works. For reference, the full file looks like this:

```
<wpf:ResourceDictionary xml:space="preserve" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:ss="urn:shemas-jetbrains-com:settings-storage-xaml" xmlns:wpf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">       
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeInspection/Highlighting/UsageCheckingInspectionLevel/@EntryValue">Off</s:String>
</wpf:ResourceDictionary>
```